# Is English translation of Baskala Shaka available?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, translation-request

The vedas form the base of Hinduism.Rigveda the most oldest and important scripture of Hinduism has 5 parts as discussed in my previous question and I am interested most in the baskala Shaka.

**So I want the English translation of Baskala shaka,is it available online anywhere?**